# Unnamed struct in Comeau compiler

Tags: c++, c

Why we can't use something like this

```
struct
{
    int bar;
} Foo;

int main() {}
```

in Comeau compiler in C++ mode, while in C mode we can?

> "ComeauTest.c", line 4: error: use of a type with no linkage to
>   declare a variable
>             with linkage   } Foo;
>       ^

Comment: What if you rename the file to cpp?

Comment: .c is the default extension for Comeau compiler online

Answer (score 4):

Per 3.5:8,

> A type without linkage shall not be used as the type of a variable or function with external linkage unless 
>   — the entity has C language linkage (7.5), or 
>   — the entity is declared within an unnamed namespace (7.3.1), or 
>   — the entity is not odr-used (3.2) or is deﬁned in the same translation unit.

Note that this is relaxed from C++98, which has (in 3.5:8):

> A name with no linkage [...] shall not be used to declare an entity with linkage.

The reason for this rule is that in order to refer to the variable from another translation unit you would need to know its type, which is not possible for an unnamed type.  In practice, this is because variables with external linkage are *mangled* with their type to generate an unambiguous name, which is not possible for an unnamed type.

However, in your code the entity `Foo` (arguably) is not odr-used, and most definitely is defined, so it should be accepted by a conforming C++11 compiler, which Comeau is not.

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov any part of the quote that needs explanation? Other compilers are either more lax than Comeau, or are conformant to C++11.

Comment: So, we can use such kind of statements only in C++11?

Comment: Regarding _"— the entity is not odr-used (3.2) or is deﬁned in the same translation unit."_  - I'm a bit unclear as to what exactly is the meaning of this statement? Is it saying that either: 
(1). Entity is not odr-used Or 
(2). Entity is odr-used  and defined in the same translation unit.
 And in both (1) and (2) the usage is well defined?